# USB 3.0 Port is not detecting usb 3.0 pendrive?

Tags: windows-7, drivers, usb-flash-drive

I am using dell notebook 3546/windows 7 64bit.
There is one usb 3.0 port which is working fine for usb 2.0 pendrive but when i connect usb 3.0 pendrive   it does't detect it.

Is there any specific driver for usb 3.0?
Please suggest .

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is the 3.0 pendrive detected by 2.0 port? If no, then possibly it doesn't connect properly due to construction (connector doesn't slide all the way in). In that case... bummer, I think.

Comment: `Windows 7` natively supports USB 3.0.  One has to do major modifications to their installation to remove the USB 3.0 driver from the installation.  So unless you removed the driver yourself its more likely the problem is a connection issue.  Even if it was removed Windows would attempt to install the driver once it detected the device.

Comment: @AcePL  .. yes 3.0 pendrive is working on 2.0 port.

Comment: What manufacturer of the Pendrive? I think this may be one of the rare combinations where USB3.0 doesn't recognize the pendrive due to the stick's fault in it's config chip... In other words: pendrive may need reflashing. Other possibility is that it's a fake 3.0 pendrive. As v123 said - check on other machine with usb3.0.

Answer (score 1):

No there is no specific driver that you can use to solve this. It sounds like a connection problem. The other possibility is that the pen drive is broken. Have you tried it in other machines? Are you certain that it is okay?

Comment: USB 3.0 pendrive is working on usb 2.0 port but not on usb 3.0 port.

Comment: Pendrive as well as usb 3.0 port is ok means there is no physical damage but its not working as i mentioned.